# How is it possible to debug IAP in Android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

**What I've done:**

- Created an app, added IAP to it, created a release build, and uploaded it to the playstore.
- I then waited an hour.
- I could then install the alpha build, test a purchase... and I noticed that my app did not react to the purchase.

**How do I debug my app so that I can step through the IAP process and observe the problem ?**
Is it possible to attach the debugger and step through the IAP process ?

---

**UPDATE**

so progress here is ridiculously slow because it takes Google about 2 hours to upload an alpha release - RIDICULOUS!

By doctoring my app with a ton of toast messages (and recording video when I run my app to check all the messages) I've found that `IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener` isn't called eventhough it is referenced in `launchPurchaseWorkflow()`, see below:

```
protected void launchPurchaseWorkflow(Activity activity, String sku)
{
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(
            activity,
            sku,
            Constants.PURCHASE_REQUEST_ID,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener,
            Constants.DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD);
}
```

As a result, a successful purchase doesn't trigger a callback into the app. So the app isn't updating the UI... After restarting the app, it does do an inventory successfully and then it detects the purchase.

What am I doing wrong ? (What isn't the documentation telling me?)

Comment: I think you missed sth, possibly you have not activated the iap product after creating it. About debug, I saw people using normal logging. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive

Comment: I noticed something interesting: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/tree/master/TrivialDrive/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trivialdrivesample/util has code that's 4 months old. I used it and it "doesn't do anything" when I run it. However, my local `\sdk\extras\google\play_billing\samples\TrivialDrive\src\com\example\android\trivialdrivesample\util` is very different and the files are dated January 4th, 2016... which one is the right one ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

**1)** Copy the "util" folder from `\sdk\extras\google\play_billing\samples\TrivialDrive\src\com\example\android\trivialdrivesample` into your project (First make sure your SDK Manager has updated to the latest "Google Play Billing Library")

**2)** From `\sdk\extras\google\play_billing\samples\TrivialDrive\src\com\example\android\trivialdrivesample\MainActivity.java` copy all the important callbacks, such as `IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener`, `IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener`, `IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener`

**3)** I wrote this utility method, which you could copy into your code also:

```
// (arbitrary) request code for the purchase flow
public static int PURCHASE_REQUEST_ID = 1234;

protected void launchPurchaseWorkflow(Activity activity, String sku)
{
    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(
            activity,
            sku,
            Constants.PURCHASE_REQUEST_ID++,// just needs to be a positive number and unique
            mPurchaseFinishedListener,
            Constants.DEVELOPER_PAYLOAD);
}
```

So far so good... there is one more thing that you need to make it all work !

**4)** You would think that since you've passed a reference `mPurchaseFinishedListener` to `mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow()` that you're good to go - but you're not !

Copy this code into the same activity that you passed in `mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + "," + data);
    if (ApplicationContext.mHelper == null) return;

    // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
    if (!ApplicationContext.mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
        // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
        // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
        // billing...
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    else {
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
    }
}
```

**NOW IT WILL WORK !!**

I spent 5 days on this "problem" - you would think that requiring `onActivityResult()` would have been better documented within trivialdrivesample. In fact, there's absolutely no method comment for it !